# Estimate about the value of certain point of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

The problems goes as follows:

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic in the closed unit disc, with $f(-\log 2)=0$, and
$$|f(z)|\leq |e^z|$$
for all $z$ with $|z|=1$, then how large can $|f(\log 2)|$? Find the best possible upper bound.

I am quite sure what the problem is testing. We can possibly get estimate by Cauchy's formula but that is obvious too sparse and did not make use of $f(-\log 2)=0$....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $g(z) = f(z)e^{-z}$, with a view to applying Schwarz lemma. Since $g(0)$ may not be zero, pre-compose it with the map
$$
\varphi_{\log(2)} = \frac{z-\log(2)}{1-\log(2)z}
$$
which maps $0$ to $-\log(2)$. Now Schwarz lemma applies to $h = g\circ \varphi_{\log(2)}$ from which you get that
$$
|h(z)| \leq |z|
$$
Now choose $z$ so that $\varphi_{\log(2)}(z) = \log(2)$, ie.
$$
z = \frac{2\log(2)}{1+\log(2)^2}
$$
Then
$$
|h(z)| = |g(\log(2))| = |f(\log(2))|
$$
since $exp(\varphi_{\log(2)}(z)) = 1$. Hence,
$$
|f(\log(2))| \leq \frac{2\log(2)}{1+\log(2)^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!! I was confused by 'the best possible', and never came up with the Schwarz's lemma! It is so clear!

Comment: No problem :) Schwarz' lemma is usually the best place to start when dealing with functions on the disc.